# Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::apt-get::update for ubuntu-bionic.example.com

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm getting the following error when running puppet on Vagrant/VirtualBox with the "ubuntu/bionic64" image:

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::apt-get::update for ubuntu-bionic.example.com (file: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-846018e2aa141a5eb79a64b4015et6f3/default.pp, line: 2, column: 5) on node ubuntu-bionic.example.com
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Environment:

- Vagrant 2.1.1
- VirtualBox 5.2.16
- Ubuntu Bionic 64
- Puppet 5.4.0

Vagrantfile:

```
...
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
...
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "apt-get update && apt-get install -y puppet"
config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
  puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
  puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
  puppet.manifest_file  = "default.pp"
  puppet.options="--verbose --debug"
end
...
```

This same exact puppet configuration was working with the `ubuntu/xenial64` box. The only thing that I changed was the `config.vm.box` line in my Vagrantfile (from `config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"` to `config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"`. I've also confirmed that my module exists and I can see it on the vm in the `/tmp` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by renaming my `apt-get` module to `apt_get`.

Going from Ubuntu Xenial to Ubuntu Bionic takes Puppet from v3.8.5 to v5.4.0. Apparently, [using hyphens in a module name isn't allowed](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_reserved.html#modules) (though it used to work).

Comment: Hyphens were never *supported* in class (or other) names in Puppet, but it is true that there was a time when they sometimes worked anyway.  Puppet 3.8 to 5 is a pretty significant jump, much more so than any 4.x to 5, and the point of increasing the major version number is to deny full backwards compatibility.  You should therefore be on the lookout for other aspects of your Puppet 3 manifest set that fail or work differently on Puppet 5.